# Resolving Nested JSON issue using Spring-Hibernate

Tags: json, spring-mvc, extjs4

I am using spring mvc and jackson for my extjs application and stuck at some thing similar.
I have my list of records returned from DB using Hibernate.
**DAO class:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<CandidateStatus> getcandidateStatus() {

    //return hibernateTemplate.find("select candstat.candidate.firstName as firstName,candstat.candidate.lastName as lastName,candstat.candidate.email as email,candstat.statusTitle as statusTitle,candstat.requirement.client.clientName as clientName,candstat.requirement.reqTitle as reqTitle from CandidateStatus as candstat");
    return hibernateTemplate.find("from CandidateStatus");
    //return hibernateTemplate.find("from CandidateStatus candstat left outer join candstat.candidate left outer join candstat.requirement left outer join candstat.requirement.client");
    //return hibernateTemplate.find("from Candidates as cands inner join cands.candidateStats");


}

**Service class**
public List<CandidateStatus> getCandidateStatusList()
{
    //return candidatesDAO.getCandidates();
    return candidatesDAO.getcandidateStatus();

}
```

**Controller class**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/candidates/view.action")
public @ResponseBody Map<String,? extends Object> view() throws Exception {

    try{            
        //List<Candidates> candidates = candidatesService.getCandidatesList();
        List<CandidateStatus> candidatestatus = candidatesService.getCandidateStatusList();

        return getMap(candidatestatus);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return getModelMapError("Error retrieving Candidates from database.");
    }


private Map<String,Object> getMap(List<CandidateStatus> candidatestatus){
    Map<String,Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String,Object>(3);
    modelMap.put("success", true);
    modelMap.put("total", candidatestatus.size());
    modelMap.put("data", candidatestatus);

    return modelMap;
}

private Map<String,Object> getModelMapError(String msg){

    Map<String,Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String,Object>(2);
    modelMap.put("message", msg);
    modelMap.put("success", false);

    return modelMap;
}
```

Before adding it to the map I want to format the JSON in a required format as per my application.I get the format in a nested manner which is not accepted by **extjs**.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 29,
        "requirement": {
            "id": 27,
            "client": {
                "id": 12,
                "clientName": "HireCraft"
            },
            "clientId": 12,
            "reqTitle": "Support Engineer"
        },
        "reqid": 27,
        "resid": 45,
        "candidate": {
            "id": 45,
            "firstName": "Vikram",
            "lastName": "",
            "email": "bj.vikram@gmail.com"
        },
        "statusTitle": "Shortlisted"
    }],
    "success":true,
    "total":7668
```

}

I want the json to be flat file like this without nesting.

```
"data": [ {
           "clientName": "ABC"
           "firstName": "Suynil",
            "lastName": "Seelam",
            "email": "ss.seelam@gmail.com",
              "reqTitle": "Java"}]success:true,total:768}
```

Can you please guide me how I can achive this.I have stuglling for long over this issue!
I tried a bit and getting something likethis.

```
private Map<String,Object> getMap(List<CandidateStatus> candidatestatus){

    Map<String,Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String,Object>(3);
    Map<String,Object> candDetails = new HashMap<String,Object>(7);


    Iterator<CandidateStatus> iterator=candidatestatus.iterator();
    CandidateStatus astring = new CandidateStatus();
    String Client;
    String Fname;
    String Lname;
    String Email;
    String Phone;
    String Status;
    String Require;

    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        astring = iterator.next();
        /*System.out.println(astring.getCandidate().getFirstName());
        System.out.println(astring.getCandidate().getLastName());
        System.out.println(astring.getCandidate().getEmail());
        System.out.println(astring.getStatusTitle());
        System.out.println(astring.getRequirement().getReqTitle());*/

        Client = astring.getRequirement().getClient().getClientName();
        Fname  = astring.getCandidate().getFirstName();
        Lname  = astring.getCandidate().getLastName();
        Email  = astring.getCandidate().getEmail();
        Phone  = astring.getCandidate().getPhone();
        Status = astring.getStatusTitle();
        Require= astring.getRequirement().getReqTitle();

        candDetails.put("clientName",Client);
        candDetails.put("firstName",Fname);
        candDetails.put("lastName",Lname);
        candDetails.put("email",Email);
        candDetails.put("phone",Phone);
        candDetails.put("statusTitle",Status);
        candDetails.put("reqTitle",Require);
        //jsonMap.put("root", candDetails);
        //System.out.println(jsonMap);
    }
    //System.out.println("----"+candDetails+"----");
    modelMap.put("success", true);
    modelMap.put("total",candDetails.size());
    modelMap.put("data",candDetails );

return modelMap;
```

Now when I try to add **candDetails** to the modelMap I get only the **LAST record**.Why???

Thanks

Comment: Just an FYI Grails can simplify the config and JSON support - and you get the same hibernate/spring frameworks :) just something to consider.

Comment: @DmitryB Thank you for sharing your views,but zero Grails knowledge here till date. :( It would help me if yo can add pointers to a few examples. :)

Comment: here you go: http://www.grails.org/Documentation

Comment: @DmitryB Thank you for that,will surely try it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your second example is valid JSON, at least according to [json.org](http://www.json.org/).  An object is defined as:

> an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma).

That tells me that JSON has to start with a '{' and end with a '}'.

Comment: There is a typo it has a start '{' bracket and the end one I have it there.Also,its just the way I want the nested one(which is returned) to be formatted.Thanks for the feed back

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work, if you change you work with map `candDetails` witch is kinda silly. In your loop you put data with same key, thats why you get data with last  iterate.

I suggest you to write custom wrapper object(lets call it CandidateStatusWrapper and build there all structure you need. Then you just return list of wrapped objects.

Wrapper example:

```
class CandidateStatusWrapper {
 String clientName;
 String firstName;
 public CandidateStatusWrapper(String clientName, String  firstName) {
   this.clientName = clientName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
}
```

Change your map:

```
 Map<String,Object> candDetails = new HashMap<String,Object>(7);
```

into list:

```
List<CandidateStatusWrapper> = new ArrayList<CandidateStatusWrapper >();
```

Loop in Controller:

```
 while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        astring = iterator.next();

        Client = astring.getRequirement().getClient().getClientName();
        Fname  = astring.getCandidate().getFirstName();

        CandidateStatusWrapper wrapped = new CandidateStatusWrapper(Client, Fname);  
        candDetails.add(wrapped);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but the reason for using Map as to build a **Name=Value** pairing relation(As I am building a JSON array)I am not sure if this would achive it(List uses default keys if  am not wrong). And you say _In your loop you put data with same key, thats why you get data with last iterate._ so,should I iterate over the keys in the list??Please correct me.

Comment: I dont see any key in your JSON example. Anyway, just generate some unique key and put your CandidateStatus objast as a value in map.
  ` candDetails.put(unique_key,candidateStatus);`

Comment: candDetails.put("clientName",Client);
**clientName= name and Client(from list)=value** 
Similarly,I want for each entry. I have it in my expected JSON
`{"data": [ {
           **"clientName": "ABC"**
           "firstName": "Suynil",
            "lastName": "Seelam",
            "email": "ss.seelam@gmail.com",
              "reqTitle": "Java"}]success:true,total:768}
`    Thank you once again.I am using Jackson for it,so is their an way to achieve this??Or else will I have to go with the Java way?Please give your views/suggestions they have been helpful.

Comment: Finally I think,I need a good way to convert a list returned by Hibernate to a MAP.(offcourse in a optimized way as I am fetching about 10000 records from DB)

Comment: so the key is "clientName"? And it will be unique for every client?

Comment: No it won't,it will be the same for all,pasting a simple json format here,`{
    "data":[
        {
             "clientName": "HireCraft",
             "firstName": "Vikram"
        },
 {
             "clientName": "ABC",
             "firstName": "Sunil"
        },
 {
             "clientName": "ABC",
             "firstName": "Sam"
        }
 ],
  "success":true,
  "total":7668
}
`So,the key would be same for all records the values,may or may not be same.(Example:**Names can be same**).I hope I am clear enough.JSON is needed as I use **EXTJS** as my UI and it accepts JSON input

Comment: can you provide example with two clients objects in JSON please?

Comment: The above one has it right??`{ "clientName": "HireCraft", "firstName": "Vikram" }`(this is one and this is second)`"clientName": "ABC", "firstName": "Sunil" }` They are 'comma' separated inside '{}' brackets.

Comment: so, this is an array of client objects, not a map. So you need to use a list here.

Comment: How can I create a name value pair using list?This is entire JSON,the formatting is not right here you can chck it on **www.jsonlint.com** `{
    "data": [
        {
           "clientName":"HireCraft",
           "reqTitle": "Support Engineer",
           "firstName":"Vikram",
           "email":"abc.com", 
           "statusTitle":"Shortlisted"
        },
 {   
           "clientName":"Capgemini",
           "reqTitle":"Support Engineer",
           "firstName":"Sunil",
           "email":"xyz.com",
           "statusTitle":"Shortlisted"
        }
 ],
 "success":true,
 "total":7668
}`

Comment: You are talking about client object(the part: `{ "clientName":"HireCraft", "reqTitle": "Support Engineer", "firstName":"Vikram", "email":"abc.com", "statusTitle":"Shortlisted" }`
And am talking about your data object, which is array of client objects, right? And FYI, you dont need to represent  `"clientName":"HireCraft", "reqTitle": "Support Engineer", "firstName":"Vikram", "email":"abc.com", "statusTitle":"Shortlisted"` aint map. The Client object will serialize in this code too. Summarize: you just need to Change your `candDetails` into List of CandidateStatusWrapper.

Comment: Ok,will try it and get back.Thank you very much for the guidance. :-)